# dexguard: encryptstrings in Activity classes?

Tags: android, obfuscation, dexguard

dexguard: Can the -encryptstrings command be used with Activity classes ?

I'm asking because it does not work for me when using

-encryptstrings

> public class com.example.my.MainActivity

or

-encryptstrings

> com.example.**MainActivity

Also the Ant log says:

> "Number of encrypted string references: 0"

Comment: why do you want to obfuscate a activity class. you can use progaurd if you want.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can encrypt all strings in specified classes, e.g.

```
-encryptstrings class com.example.my.MainActivity
```

If it doesn't seem to work for your code, you can contact us with more details.

(I am the developer of ProGuard and DexGuard)

Comment: I am trying to get a basic understanding of how to specify string encryption using the command -encryptstring in the file dexguard-project.txt. For example, I see `-encryptstrings "android.content.pm.PackageInfo", "packageName", "versionName", ... ` What does it mean?

Comment: -encryptstrings  not working on my side ..from which version you have introduced encryptstrings ?